# Why is the list value in my Tic Tac Toe game adding to the list multiple times and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, list, loops, pygame

```
import pygame,random,time #importing
#-------initalizing/setting screen------#
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
#---------variables and lists-----------#
guessedNumbersX = []
guessedNumbersO = []
numbersNotGuessed = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
computerGuess = 0
isComputerGuessTrue  = False
num = 0
#-----------checking function------------#
def check():
if isComputerGuessTrue == False:
  if xpos >= 100 and xpos <= 300 and ypos >= 0 and ypos <= 200:
  
    if 1 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(1)
    elif 1 not in guessedNumbersX or 1 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(1)
  elif xpos >= 300 and xpos <= 500 and ypos >= 0 and ypos <= 200:
    if 2 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(2)
    elif 2 not in guessedNumbersX or 2 not in guessedNumbersO:
    guessedNumbersX.append(2)
  elif xpos >= 500 and xpos <= 700 and ypos >= 0 and ypos <= 200:
    if 3 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(3)
    elif 3 not in guessedNumbersX or 3 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(3)
  elif xpos >= 100 and xpos <= 300 and ypos >= 200 and ypos <= 400:
    if 4 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(4)
    elif 4 not in guessedNumbersX or 3 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(4)
  elif xpos >= 300 and xpos <= 500 and ypos >= 200 and ypos <= 400:
    if 5 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(5)
    elif 5 not in guessedNumbersX or 5 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(5)
  elif xpos >= 500 and xpos <= 700 and ypos >= 200 and ypos <= 400:
    if 6 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(6)
    elif 6 not in guessedNumbersX or 6 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(6)
  elif xpos >= 100 and xpos <= 300 and ypos >= 400 and ypos <= 600:
    if 7 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(7)
    elif 7 not in guessedNumbersX or 7 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(7)
  elif xpos >= 300 and xpos <= 500 and ypos >= 400 and ypos <= 600:
    if 8 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(8)
    elif 8 not in guessedNumbersX or 8 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(8)
  elif xpos >= 500 and xpos <= 700 and ypos >= 400 and ypos <= 600:
    if 9 in numbersNotGuessed:
      numbersNotGuessed.remove(9)
    elif 9 not in guessedNumbersX or 9 not in guessedNumbersO:
      guessedNumbersX.append(9)
    #----------starting game loop-----------#
    game = True
    xpos = 0
    ypos = 0
    while game:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
    #-------------making events-------------#
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
      running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
  
      x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      xpos = x
      ypos = y
  
      isComputerGuessTrue = True
  
    #-------------Drawing 9 squares---------#
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (225,225,225),(100,0,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),(300,0,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (225,225,225),(500,0,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),(100,200,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (225,225,225),(300,200,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),(500,200,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (225,225,225),(100,400,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),(300,400,200,200))
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (225,225,225),(500,400,200,200))

      print(guessedNumbersX)
      print(guessedNumbersO)
      print(numbersNotGuessed)
      check()


      if isComputerGuessTrue == True:

        num = random.choice(numbersNotGuessed)
        numbersNotGuessed.remove(num)
        guessedNumbersO.append(num)
        isComputerGuessTrue = False

      pygame.display.flip()
```

I know this is alot, but I didn't know how to shorten it for you guys because I don't know where the error is in the code, but it basically won't stop adding the value that I click on the screen to guessedNumbersX but the computer part is working working. I'm having alot of trouble figuring out this bug, and that is why I came on stack overflow, but I know it is alot of code to take in   but it is appreciated if you can help. Obviously it is in pygame and it would help if I could get help! Thank you!

I am currently coding on repl.it and I plan to get better coding software soon, but here s the link - https://repl.it/@WeirdDragon/Tic-Tac-toe-2#main.py

Comment: Where is `check()` actually called?

Comment: "I know this is alot, but I didn't know how to shorten it for you guys because I don't know where the error is in the code" Try taking something out. Does the error still happen? No, then keep going. Yes, then see if you can set up that part by itself and still get the error. Rinse and repeat. https://sscce.org

Comment: The indenting in this code block is all messed up, which in python makes it extremely challenging to follow the code flow. Can you fix the indenting so that when you display the question on your screen it matches the code that you are trying to run?

Comment: Glenn Mackintosh the indenting is fine, but once I put it into stack overflow it got a little messed up

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the issue: when the mouse is clicked you store the position in `xpos` and `ypos`. This value is only updated after the next mouse click. Meanwhile, your check function keeps running and - because xpos and ypos are not updated or changed - it will keep adding the same value to your list.

[SOLUTION]: Try changing your `xpos` and `ypos` - after appending the value to the list - to a number or value that causes your check function to do nothing i.e. bypass appending the value to the list.

[NOTE]: This answer is a mere guess, as we have no context to when your `check()` function is called. If you can, please give a link to the full version of your program (through github or pastebin etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Just to let everyone know, the reason I was having this bug was because in my if statements in the check function I used or instead of and, and it started working. Basically the number could only be added to one list, and because it was not in the other list it would keep on appending so I changed all the or's to and's.